# Swipe to change views

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uipagecontrol, swipe

Is the following easy to code?

I have a tableview and when the user selects a cell a detail view is loaded.
I want to allow the user to navigate throughout the items/detail-view representing the items in the tableview by left and right swipes, working in the same way as e.g. the home-screen of the iphone (e.g. while swiping, one page is moving off the screen and the next appears).

I have seen this implemented in the MobileRSS-APP, so it is possible, but I just have a hard-time figuring out the way to do it properly.

Thanks a million in advance! I am still trying to find my feet with cocoa-touch...

Comment: +1, I'm also interested in learning how this works. The Reeder app does that by scrolling up and down, so maybe EGOTableviewPullRefresh might be a good place to start researching on similar techniques.

Comment: Based on my comment, I did a search (I should have searched before :) and there is a blog post in iDev Recipes describing exactly what I wanted: http://idevrecipes.com/2010/12/28/how-does-the-reeder-iphone-app-swipe-up-and-down-between-articles/

Comment: Thanks Irene, that is very helpful too. The second answer seems to be more in the direction I am thinking of, but this example gives me an answer to another question, allowing a pull-down to return to the list (as alternative to the back button)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a secret, Apple provides the sample code called the [PageControl](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PageControl/Introduction/Intro.html) that demonstrates exactly what you want to achieve:

> This application primarily demonstrates use of UIScrollView's paging functionality to use horizontal scrolling as a mechanism for navigating between different pages of content.

I implemented it in [many of my apps](http://sunflowerapps.com).

Comment: A quick view is what I expected form the PageControl, but I didn't get a chance yet to have an in-depth look. But would that mean that instead of loading the detailed view XIB when a cell is selected that I load a new ViewController and pass the reference to the selected cell and there build the detailedView (and in initialization also load the detailViews beside it)?

Comment: The "detail view" is a scroll view that holds every detail views, you load it by giving it an index, and meanwhile, lazily load other views so when user swipes, the other views are ready to be shown. Take a look at the sample code, and you'll see what you have to do. It does not contain much code.

Answer (score 2):

The iphone home screen (springboard) works with a scroll view set to paging enabled.

```
UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
[scrollView setPagingEnabled:YES];
```

Then, lets say there's two pages of apps to swipe through - you set the content size of the scroll view to twice the width of your view:

```
[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width*2, self.view.frame.size.height)];
```

And thats how that is done. :) I don't know if its the same for the MobileRSS-APP.

Things to bear in mind:

1. This isn't the default way a table view works. You might get your app rejected by apple. A table view is meant to work by clicking.
2. You could probably replicate the functionality without using a scroll view using touches methods and the navigation controller. A good tutorial describing how to detect swipes on your view is here: http://www.dosomethinghere.com/2009/07/23/simple-swipe-detection-in-the-iphone-sdk/

In the last method in that tutorial where there is the NSLog("swipe right") you could replace that with `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]` which would replicate pressing the "back" button in the navigation bar.

I don't know what you could do for swipe left though..... if you wanted to do this on the table view you'll have to do some complicated maths determining how far the table view has been scrolled. Or you could test for touch events on the cells themselves, but thats something you wil have to look into. :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Regarding your comment about the table's default behavior, I think Luuk wants the scrolling for the detail view, and not for the table view itself, so it sounds safe to me..