# Using iOS PageControl in Hybrid application

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app, pagecontrol

Is there any way to use iOS [PageControl](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/PageControl/Introduction/Intro.html) in my *JavaScript* **Hybrid** app to be able to swipe it's pages in iPhone, like the way we can change pages in Safari and etc?

Like the screenshot and also what is mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4931134/swipe-to-change-views)

[image]

Image is taken from [this article](http://www.macworld.com/article/2886383/6-time-saving-safari-gestures-for-iphone-and-ipad.html)

Answer (score 0):

There is a cordova plugin for native page transitions
https://github.com/Telerik-Verified-Plugins/NativePageTransitions

But I'm not sure if it includes the animation you want. If it doesn't include it, then you can fork the plugin and add it yourself or create a new plugin for the pageControl

Comment: Thanks and sorry for my late reply. The plugin is good, but the problem is that I want to trigger **iOS horizontal swipe gesture which is reserved for back/forth navigation**! I can't use angular swipe. I only want to have it in my Hybrid application which is run in iPhones